# この町は、地下鉄が通った上に、**デパートもできて**、便利になった。looks awkward to me

Tags: reading-comprehension, grammar, comprehension

I can accept この町は、地下鉄が通った上に、**デパートに行きもできて**、便利になった。
Or この町は、地下鉄が通った上に、**デパートで買い物もできて**、便利になった。
But この町は、地下鉄が通った上に、**デパートもできて**、便利になった。 looks awkward to me. It's like 'One is able to department'????

Comment: できる has more meanings than "to be able to". What else might you do with a department store? https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does できる mean in this context?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13519/5010) / [Is this phrase missing something?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44420/5010) By the way 行きもできて is ungrammatical. Did you want to say 行けて or 行くこともできて?

Comment: @naruto  yes, 行くこともできて, my bad.
行けて and 行くこともできて mean the same thing right?....行けて is in potential form right?

Answer (score 2):

About constructions, できた means "built".

デパートもできて means "moreover, a department store opened".